# linux kernel development

Tags: linux, assembly, kernel

I am currently reading 'Linux Kernel Development' by Robert Love and I do not understand what this bit of assembly is doing.

Basically, in each process kernel stack, there is a `struct thread_info` which resides at the end of the stack.  Now, on the x86 architecture, we can apparently grab this (assuming 8KB stack size) by using the following assembly

```
movl $-8192, %eax
andl %esp, %eax
```

So basically ANDing the stack pointer by 0xffffe000.  I'm confused as to what is going on here?  I don't see why masking the least significant 13 bits of `%esp` takes us to the struct.  I know I'll feel stupid once it is explained, but it is bugging me.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm currently reading this book and I have even more basic question: how do you know that `-8192` is `0xffffe000`? How negative numbers are stored in CPU's registers?

Comment: @patryk.beza The negative numbers are stored during 1's and 2's complements [Read more here](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/binary/signed-binary-numbers.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The stack grows downwards, so the end of the stack is the lowest address in the stack, and the structure's starting address. And stacks are stored at multiples of 8KB. Therefore, erasing the 13 least significant bits gets the lowest address of the stack and therefore the start of the structure. Does this make sense?

Comment: But I thought %esp pointed to the bottom of the stack?  When the struct is pushed on to the stack at the end, %esp is decremented.

Comment: The stack starts from a high memory address (when stuff is pushed, the stack pointer decreases). %esp points to the bottom of the stack, in that it points to the "current" bottom, rather than the bottom of the space that the stack is allowed to grow in.

Comment: Ah, see I thought the struct was just pushed on at the end of everything rather than just shoved right down in the pit of the stack when the process is initialised and given it's own stack. OK, thanks lijie